# How do I remove text between two "tags" in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am using Google Apps Script to make documents from a "template". This template in Google Docs has the following format:

```
(Text above the area of interest...) Culpa cillum excepteur cupidatat cillum ex.

{mySpecialText}
Est consectetur irure non quis sint exercitation velit qui consequat incididunt officia laborum ea veniam.
{/mySpecialText}

(More ignored text here...) Tempor voluptate irure laboris occaecat enim ipsum consequat velit.
```

The text between the two tags `{mySpecialText}` and `{/mySpecialText}` should be deleted, in addition to the tags. How do I go about doing this? My current code shown below removes the tags but not the paragraph in between.

```
/**
 * @param doc - a `Document` instance.
 * @param sectionId - the name of the tag
 */
function removeSection (doc, sectionId) {
  var startTag = '{' + sectionId + '}'
  var endTag = '{/' + sectionId + '}'

  var body = doc.getBody()

  var startElem = body.findText(startTag)
  var endElem = body.findText(endTag)

  if (startElem == null) {
    return Logger.log('Couldn\'t find startElem with tag "' + startTag + '"')
  }
  if (endElem == null) {
    return Logger.log('Couldn\'t find endElem with tag "' + endTag + '"')
  }

  startElem = startElem.getElement()
  endElem = endElem.getElement()

  var toRemove = []
  var currentElement = startElem

  while (currentElement !== null && !isSameElement(currentElement, endElem)) {
    toRemove.push(currentElement)
    currentElement = currentElement.getNextSibling()
  }

  toRemove.push(endElem)

  for (var i = 0; i < toRemove.length; i++) {
    toRemove[i].removeFromParent()
  }
}
```

Comment: `startElem.getElement()` gives you the `Text` element. But what you need here is the `Paragraph`. So you would have to write `startElem = startElem.getElement().getParent()`. And the same goes for `endElem`. But doing it this way is problematic anyway since you can only delete whole paragraphs. What if the tags are somewhere in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: @SpiderPig These elements are meant to be used to block out "sections" in the document so they will not in their current form be in the middle of a paragraph. What would the best way to go forward on this idea, being that `Text` and `Paragraph` elements are so different? Do you know what constitutes a `Paragraph`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the entire paragraph between the tags. Assuming this is only one paragraph, you could retrieve the paragraph element and delete it as follows:

```
var removeme = startElem.getParent().getNextSibling().asParagraph();
removeme.removeFromParent();
```

If there could be multiple paragraphs, you could write some script with a loop that detects whether the next sibling of `removeme` is an end tag. If it is not, then delete the paragraph, otherwise stop the loop.